# How do I extract an object(array) from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, extract

Say I have the following dataset:

```
const art = {
    'fields': [
        {title:'Title 1'}, 
        {'text': [
            {spaces: '1'}, {link: 'This is a link'}, {mouse: 'Yes'}
        ]}, 
        {title: 'Title 2'}, 
        {title:'Title 3'},
        {'text': [
            {spaces: '2'}, {link: 'This is a different link'}, {mouse: 'No'}
        ]},
    ]};
```

I would like to extract a new object(array) from the "spaces" property. In addition to that, I need to to identify those "title" objects that do not have a "spaces" property associated with them with a blank value.

I'd like to end up with something like this:

```
newArray = ['', '1', '', '', '2']
```

Is this possible? Forgive me if my terminology isn't great. New at this.

Comment: do you have an exact result, you would like to get and your try?

Comment: Essentially, I'm trying to extract the data in the "text.spaces" field into its own array and at the same time identify objects that do not have this data.

Comment: please add the wanted result of the given data.

Comment: The syntax you're using in the output example doesn't make sense.

Comment: Asked and answered, dozens, if not hundreds, of times.  Have you googled?  It will probably lead you back to an answer right here on Stackoverflow

Comment: The wanted result is in the newArray as I pointed out above

Comment: "Asked and answered, dozens, if not hundreds ..." Yes, I have. I haven't found the answer. That's why I am here asking. If you know where the answer exists, please, by all means, point me in the right direction.

Comment: `{''}` or `{'1'}` are not valid JavaScript objects. It can be array `['1']`, object `{spaces: '1'}`, or just string `'1'`

Comment: Okay. I understand. I am only interested in the string values. I'll modify the output so that it is represented that way. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't be too hard.  Try Javascript's `map()` function...

```
const art = {
    'fields': [
        {title:'Title 1'}, 
        {'text': [
            {spaces: '1'}, {link: 'This is a link'}, {mouse: 'Yes'}
        ]}, 
        {title: 'Title 2'}, 
        {title:'Title 3'},
        {'text': [
            {spaces: '2'}, {link: 'This is a different link'}, {mouse: 'No'}
        ]},
    ]};

const spaces = art.fields.map(function(field) {
  if(field.text) {
    return field.text[0].spaces;
  }
  return '';
});

console.log("Spaces?");

console.log(spaces);
```

And the results...

```
"Spaces?"
["", "1", "", "", "2"]
```

See the code working on [JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/xarisaweje/edit?html,js,console).  Map returns a function's result for an iteration over an array.  Check out the [Mozilla Developer Network Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map` method to calculate a value for each item in the `art.fields` array.

```js
const art = {
    'fields': [
        {title:'Title 1'}, 
        {'text': [
            {spaces: '1'}, {link: 'This is a link'}, {mouse: 'Yes'}
        ]}, 
        {title: 'Title 2'}, 
        {title:'Title 3'},
        {'text': [
            {spaces: '2'}, {link: 'This is a different link'}, {mouse: 'No'}
        ]},
    ]};

var newArray = art.fields.map(function(o){
  return 'text' in o ? o.text[0].spaces : '';
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

```
const newArr = art.fields.map(space => {
  return {...space.text}
});
```

so I'm assuming you want to return a new array containing an object of the text array

Comment: Not exactly. I only want to return the value of the spaces property. For those objects that do not have a spaces property, I want to return a blank space ' '.

Answer (score 0):

if your text array will have multiple spaces then it should loop through it and add in spaces value like below:

```js
const art = {
  'fields': [{
      title: 'Title 1'
    },
    {
      'text': [{
        spaces: '1'
      }, {
        link: 'This is a link'
      }, {
        mouse: 'Yes'
      }]
    },
    {
      title: 'Title 2'
    },
    {
      title: 'Title 3'
    },
    {
      'text': [{
        spaces: '2'
      }, {
        link: 'This is a different link'
      }, {
        mouse: 'No'
      }]
    },
  ]
};


var res = art.fields.reduce((ini, curr, idx) => {
  if (curr.text) {
    curr.text.forEach(arr => {
      arr.spaces && ini.push(arr.spaces);
    });
  } else {
    ini.push('');
  }
  return ini;
}, [])
console.log(res);
```