# How to display an array as a single column in a table in react/js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, html-table

I'm trying to validate null values for required columns in an excel sheet and trying to display the result as a table with columns as - row number, null value column names.

Since it is possible for many columns in a row to have null values, I'm storing those columns as an array.

While displaying it in a table, I'm not able to get the comma delimiter in a  element.

Any advice to how to display an array with comma delimeters like `[a,b,c,--]` in a single column `abc` in a table ?

```
Presenting a sample code base 

export default function App() {
 const names = ["a", "b","c"];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th>Names</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <td>{names}</td>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
This is giving output as
```

| Names |
| --- |
| abc |

```
Expecting output as
```

| Names |
| --- |
| a,b,c |

Comment: I recommend you take a look at an answer I have to a similar question: [How do I extract an object(array) from an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60384346/2430549)

Comment: printing on console is different I believe to the html.

Comment: It should be fine!  Change `console.log(...)` to `return(...)`.  Don't forget that `map()` ***must return*** a value.  So, you'll have `return(<div>{things.map((thing)=>{return (<b>{thing}</b>);}</div>)}`.  If that works, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: If it is just an array with letters as strings, you can always convert the array to one string with delimiter using the Array.join(delimiter). For example in your code: <td>{names.join(',')}</td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array with delimiter in this case it should be `,`;

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-jang-136jn?file=/src/App.js:0-343)

```
export default function App() {
  const names = ["a", "b", "c"];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>Names</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{names.join(",")}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```